# Ionic3 NullInjectorError: No provider for NavController

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm getting the error `NullInjectorError: No provider for NavController`. I searched for it and I know I shouldn't inject it into the appcomponent. I'm not doing so, but I still get the error. I have appComponent which is my rootcomponent. As startpage i'm setting my StartPage. In this StartPage i'm injecting the What am I doing wrong?

AppComponent template:

```
<ion-nav #content [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

AppComponent:

```
export class AppComponent {
    rootPage: any = StartPage; //Setting my start page

    constructor(
        private platform: Platform,
        private statusBar: StatusBar,
        private splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.statusBar.styleBlackTranslucent();
            this.splashScreen.hide();
        });

    } 
}
```

StartPage:

```
export class StartPage {
    constructor(private navController: NavController){

    }

    signin(){
        this.navController.push(LoginPage);
    }

    signup(){
        this.navController.push(SignupPage);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you resolve this issue ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try to import NavCtrl at the top of the file, where you need it (at the top of the StartPage?):

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
```

And adding it into constructor, as you did, should be enough.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I got that import. Probably won't even compile without.

Comment: try opening with vscode editor. maybe it will show if something is missing.

Comment: I compared my project with yours and the difference I see, that the code in viewDidLoad in app.component I have in constructor. Maybe this is the issue? check, If not,I'll try to think of something else.

Comment: I suppose that your page is generated with ```ionic g page ... --no-module``` Just in case, show all of StartPage code, maybe something is missing. Maybe 

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-start',
  templateUrl: 'start.html',
})
```